# katana teleop using phantom

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is it possible to teleop katana arm robot with a phantom using ros packages?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67636/katana-teleop-using-phantom/) by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no reason why you couldn't do that. The [phantom_omni](http://www.ros.org/wiki/phantom_omni) package gives you a 6D pose (the pose that you want the end effector to be in). You'd have to create an arm navigation configuration package for your complete robot (like [kurtana_arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kurtana_arm_navigation)), then you can write a node that sends the pose from the phantom as a goal to the `move_arm` action. The motion planner would then plan a path to the desired pose and execute it on the robot.

Maybe even better would be to implement an inverse kinematics controller instead of using motion planning; perhaps this would allow you to send goals more frequently, allowing for a smoother motion of the arm. The package [katana_ikfast_kinematics_plugin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/katana_ikfast_kinematics_plugin) provides a 5D IK for the Katana arm.

You can also have a look at the [pr2_omni_teleop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_omni_teleop) package, where they developed something similar for the PR2.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1